# Acrylic Brush in Spiltview

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, fluent-design

```
<Page
x:Class="DOCompare.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<SplitView DisplayMode="CompactInline" IsPaneOpen="False" x:Name="HomeSplit" CompactPaneLength="52" OpenPaneLength="360" Style="{StaticResource SystemControlAcrylicWindowBrush}">
    <SplitView.Pane>
    ...
    </SplitView.Pane>
    <SplitView.Content>
    ...
    </SplitView.Content>
</SplitView>
```

this is my XAML code, and I wanted to apply acrylic Brush in my splitview (Background Acrylic, Not in App). But it doesn't work.

What is problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i solved it!

```
PaneBackground="{StaticResource SystemControlAcrylicWindowBrush}"
```

We should use above instead of style

Comment: ha, thanks for this... I was really scratching my head